# Where are questions about QuickBooks on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange site in which questions about the accounting software QuickBooks are on-topic?

Not about bookkeeping and accounting in general, but how to use the application (e.g. menus, settings, file formats).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such questions would be on-topic on [Super User](http://superuser.com). Quoting their [on-topic guidance](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> [...]
>
> - computer software,

How to use the QuickBooks application is very much a question about computer software, from an end-user perspective.

There already is a [`quickbooks` tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/quickbooks) on the site.